# Pandas - Pivot Table based on Column A while ensuring order in Column B

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following data frame containing three columns:

```
Text                    Line_Number     Value
521998135749            15              Pamphlet
2716253485              15              Local
SRM                     15              Info
12 B WAY                16              Info
DANUBE                  17              Info
520898004500            18              Pamphlet
2746254789              18              Local
OLO                     18              Info
14TH ST N               19              Info
VOLGA                   20              Info
534598195562            21              Pamphlet
2867365825              21              Local
JDM                     21              Info
896 VT                  22              Info
FALLS RD                23              Info
```

I want to transform it such that `Line_Number` column and the unique values in `Value` column form the headers of the new table. The values in `Text` column should be filled appropriately. The challenge here is, if certain values in the columns are missing, they should be left blank as shown below:

```
Line_Number      Pamphlet            Local             Info
15               521998135749        2716253485        SRM
16                                                     12 B WAY 
17                                                     DANUBE
18               520898004500        2746254789        OLO
19                                                     14TH ST N   
20                                                     VOLGA   
21               534598195562        2867365825        JDM
22                                                     896 VT
23                                                     FALLS RD
```

The table must be filled strictly according to the order of values in "Line_Number" column.

There are many examples of transposing and pivoting tables, but I haven't come across any examples where the order of a column is preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pivot` and `reindex` by unique so:

```
(df.pivot('Line_Number', 'Value', 'Text')
 .reindex(index=df['Line_Number'].unique(), columns=df['Value'].unique()))
```

Comment: How can I replace the `nan` values with some string?